# Whitelist AWS self in inbound connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdo, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am deploying a laravel installation in AWS, everything runs perfectly when I allow it to recieve all inbound traffic (EC2>Network&Security>Security Groups>Edit inbound rules.), if I turn off inbound traffic and limit it to an IP it doesnt load the webpage it gives me this error:

**PDO Exception SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out**

However for security reasons I dont want this setup like this, I dont want anyone being able to even try to reach my webapp. Everything is being hosted in AWS, I dont have any external entities, its running in RDS and EC2. I added en elastic IP address and whitelisted it, but that didnt work either. I followed every step in this tutorial : **http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html#php-laravel-tutorial-generate**

Environmental variables are working as well as dependencies, well.. pretty much everything unless I restrict inbound traffic as I mentioned.

How do I whitelist AWS own instance then to make this work with better security?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you share the same security group between your EC2 instance and your RDS cluster? If yes, the reason is probably, that when removing the rule to allow all incoming requests, the EC2 instance can't reach the RDS cluster anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851629/connecting-to-rds-from-ec2?rq=1) is what you may be looking for.

> You should enable inbound access from the EC2 **security group** associated with your EC2 instance, instead of the EC2 IP address.

Answer (score 0):

More than just adding an elastic IP address to your AWS instance you need to do two more things.

1. Assign the elastic IP to your AWS instance ( yes is not the same as just adding it to the instance, you must specify )
2. White list the internal IP that it generates once you link it to your app.
3. ?????
4. Profit